Is there any way to start an app activity (not a notification) from the background on Wear OS 4 and higher?
I am writing a Wear OS app that should send reminders to the user requesting a YES/NO feedback.
The reminders have to work when the app is in the background as well.
I could do this with a notification, BUT I want to customize the YES/NO touchscreen buttons so that they take up ALL the screen (LEFT HALF = YES, RIGHT HALF = NO), so the user can provide the feedback more easily, almost without looking at the watch.
However, this format seems to be not achievable within the available notification options.
I had done it using OVERLAY permissions on a Wear OS 3 device, BUT it looks like this has been prohibited from Wear OS 4....
Any suggestions?
Thanks a lot!
Angelo

it works fine for me on wear os 4. the permission is no longer necessary if the api is 33 or above.
maybe show some code.

Thanks @Veit! I am working with a Samsung Galaxy Watch 4, and I have included in the manifest the 'SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW' authorization. However when the reminders are generated, I get the vibration and sound, but nothing happens on the screen. To see my notification I must open the App. Also, if I call the 'candrawoverlays' function, it always returns "false". I have looked in the watch settings for an option to activate the OVERLAY but I couldn't find it. I am thinking that Samsung blocked this feature. Before this I tried it on a Xiaomi Watch 2 pro (WearOS 3.5) and everything worked...

"when the reminders are generated" - what kind of reminders are you generating? you need to start an activity.
the overlay permission is no longer needed on 33 i guess - i removed it from my code
